# Blurry fonts on external display MacBook Pro M1 Pro MacOS Ventura

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, display, ventura

I have a 1440p 27" external display with MacBook Pro M1 Pro with Ventura connected. I found a lot of info about blurry fonts, HiDPI etc and people recommend using BetterDisplay. So now I have a lot of HiDPI resolution options, but when I choose 1280x720 (HiDPI) (also called "native") everything becomes really big and impossible to use. But if I choose bigger resolution like 2560x1439 (HiDPI) fonts become blurry. Has anyone encountered such a problem?

MacOS:
[image: MacOS]

Windows 11:
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

HiDPI resolutions are scaled resolutions, and if you're not using a display with high-density pixels, then it's going to look rubbish.

Your display is 109 pixels per inch. Mac Retina displays are 218ppi -- twice as many per inch. (The M1 Pro MBP is even higher!)

Retina displays scale everything to twice the size, because their pixels are half the size!

The 1280 x 720 scaled resolution is also scaled to twice the size, on the assumption that your pixels are also tiny. But, in your case, they're not, so everything is *actually* twice the size.

The best result with this display is going to be the native 2560 x 1440, without using BetterDisplay. (Not the pseudo-native scaled resolution of half that!)

However, text on macOS really doesn't look good, unless you're using high-density pixel displays.

Comment: Thank you for answer! But I don't think this is the case, I have Windows machine too and it performs better when connected to this display than MacBook. When using 2560x1440 (LoDPI) text looks crumbly (worse than 1080p on windows).

Comment: @FreziDok Windows uses 'sub-pixel rendering' to smooth text on standard displays. MacOS doesn't do this, because it's computationally expensive, and because it wants everyone to use hi-DPI displays. (And because MS owns the patent.) It shouldn't look *that* bad, though. I used to have a 27" 2K display, and the text was "OK", certainly. Can you provide some screenshots?

Comment: Sure! Added screenshots to question.

Comment: @FreziDok To my eyes, the Windows example looks 'wispy', grey and thin; neither is particularly smooth.